# Masstransit cannot access host machine RabbitMQ from a docker container

Tags: rabbitmq, .net-core, masstransit

I created a simple .net core console application with docker support. Following
Masstransit code fails to connect to RabbitMQ instance on host machine. But similar implementation using RabitMq.Client is able to connect to host machine RabbitMQ instance.

Masstransit throws

> MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionException: Connect
>   failed: ctas@192.168.0.9:5672/ --->
>   RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException:

host machine ip : 192.168.0.9

using Masstransit

```
        string rabbitMqUri = "rabbitmq://192.168.0.9/";
        string userName = "ctas";
        string password = "ctas@123";
        string assetServiceQueue = "hello";


       var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
       {
           var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqUri), hst =>
           {
               hst.Username(userName);
               hst.Password(password);
           });

           cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host,
                assetServiceQueue, e =>
                {
                    e.Consumer<AddNewAssetReceivedConsumer>();

                });

       });


        bus.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Service Running.... Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
        bus.Stop();
```

Using RabbitMQ Client

```
        public static void Main()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.UserName = "ctas";
        factory.Password = "ctas@123";
        factory.VirtualHost = "watcherindustry";
        factory.HostName = "192.168.0.9";
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                                 autoAck: true,
                                 consumer: consumer);

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestClient.dll"]
```

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: You are not connecting to virtual host in MassTransit, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the response. I managed to resolve this issue. My findings are as follows.

to connect to a rabbitmq instance on another docker container, they have to be moved/connected to the same network. To do this
create a newtork

```
   docker network create -d bridge my_bridge
```

connect both app and rabbitmq containers to same network

```
   docker network connect my_bridge <container name>
```

For masstransit uri use rabbitmq container **IP on that network or container name**

To connect rabbitmq instance of host machine from a app on docker container.
masstransit uri should include **machine name**( I tried IP, that did not work)

Comment: I was missing the network configuration

Answer (score 1):

I created an [example](https://github.com/gertjvr/masstransit-docker), and was able to connect my host, using the preview package from masstransit.

Start rabbitmq in docker and expose ports on the host

```
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3-management
```

Build and run console app.

```
docker build -t dotnetapp .
docker run -d -e RABBITMQ_URI=rabbitmq://guest:guest@172.17.0.2:5672 --name some-dotnetapp dotnetapp
```

To verify your receiving messages run

```
docker logs some-dotnetapp --follow
```

you should see the following output

```
Application is starting...
Connecting to rabbitmq://guest:guest@172.17.0.2:5672
Received: Hello, World [08/12/2017 04:35:53]
Received: Hello, World [08/12/2017 04:35:58]
Received: Hello, World [08/12/2017 04:36:03]
Received: Hello, World [08/12/2017 04:36:08]
Received: Hello, World [08/12/2017 04:36:13]
...
```

Notes:

172.17.0.2 was my-rabbit container ip address but you can replace it with your machine ip address
http://localhost:15672 is the rabbitmq management console log in with guest as username and password.

Lastly [portainer.io](https://portainer.io/install.html) is a very useful application to visually view you local docker environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using virtual host in MassTransit configuration too, not sure why you decided to omit it.

```
var host = cfg.Host("192.168.0.9", "watcherindustry", hst =>
{
     hst.Username(userName);
     hst.Password(password);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it did not work with or without vitual host. I also used your Host overload as oppose to URI based overload.

Comment: As you can see, the exception is produced by RabbitMQ client library, so I would not expect this is something related to MassTransit.

Comment: Do you mean MassTransit.RabbitMQ, I am using (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.RabbitMQ/4.0.0.1216-develop). Otherwise I dont have any RabbitMQ lib reference.

Comment: No, clearly the exception is `RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException`

Comment: Some libs are ILMerged. You don't get references to Newtonsoft.Json either but it is widely used.

Comment: I have included image of my project Dependencies as well. I dont see version difference of RabbitMQ.Client I am using and what  MassTransit.RabbitMQ is using.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Alexey Zimarev comment to your question, if your rabbit runs on a container then it should be on your docker-compese file and then use that entry in your endpoint definition to connect to rabbit because docker creates an internal network on which you are agnostic from source code...

```
rabbitmq:
     container_name: "rabbitmq-yournode01"
     hostname: rabbit
     image: rabbitmq:3.6.6-management
     environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=yourusergoeshere
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=yourpasswordgoeshere
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=vhost
     volumes:
        - rabbit-volume:/var/lib/rabbitmq
     ports:
        - "5672:5672"
        - "15672:15672"
```

In your app settings you should have something lie:

```
 "ConnectionString": "host=rabbitmq:5672;virtualHost=vhost;username=yourusergoeshere;password=yourpasswordgoeshere;timeout=0;prefetchcount=1",
```

And if you'd use EasyNEtQ you could do:

```
 _bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(_connectionString); // The one above
```

I hope it helps,

Juan

Comment: Thanks, but RabbitMQ is on the host machine. Application runing inside the docker container is trying to access that RabbitMQ instance using masstransit. Masstransit connection fails in that setup but RabbitMq client succeeds.